# Codename one can't get correct storage path on Android

Tags: android, storage, codenameone

We are trying to included some bundled images with our app which integrates with URLImages but unzipping them into the storage folder (with url paths that match those expected).
It works fine on ios and in the simulator, but is failing to find or have access to the correct path on Android.

```
String storagePath = getStoragePath(url + suffix);
OutputStream os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(storagePath);
... 

getStoragePath(String string){
    for (String s : Arrays.asList("/", "\\", "%", "?", "*", ":", "=")) {
        string = StringUtil.replaceAll(string, s, "_");
    }
    return string;
}
```

On android the path seems to be wrong from this.
Is there any way to manually get the correct path and then use FileSystemStorage to open the output stream?
I'd rather not hard code any paths since they do occasionally change, and can vary from system to system.
Any other options I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are coding to an implementation detail which is specifically hidden and might change in the future. `FileSystemStorage` & `Storage` are logically separate and shouldn't be mixed.

If you want access from `FileSystemStorage` you should always only use that API and avoid `Storage`.

This is by design, in some OS's storage is implemented in a very unique way that doesn't map to a filesystem file at all...

Comment: But even if it's prone to change the interface should be consistant.  
My question really boils down to why in Android does Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream() not make an output stream in the applications storage?  
Is URLImage doing something behind the scenes to make it work?

Comment: No. Android device A will use one path and Android device B will use a different path. Some devices provide no way to reach that path at all... `URLImage` isn't doing anything like that and we don't mix the API's, they have completely separate implementation and usage.

Comment: so if I use Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(storagePath) it should work, but it doesn't. On android the path doesn't exist, or is not pointing at the correct place. is there something I need to generate the folder first

Comment: Again. Storage name not path. Storage is a flat location completely separate from filesystem which you should only access thru the storage API.

Comment: Path was probably the wrong variable name. I'm not using anything except for flat files. Just images in the vien of urlImage. It is not working on android.

Comment: FileSystemStorage != Storage. They have no guarantee of being in the same place. You are relying on a quirk in the simulator and expect that to be the situation in the device.